# Screenshot not taken when using phantomjs from java

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, phantomjs

I am a beginner in Phantomjs and java. What i am trying to do is take a screenshot using java in eclipse. I have downloaded the phantomjs and placed a demo javascript file "hello.js" in the executable folder. If I run it in command-line its working fine and screenshot saved in the relative folder. Now I am trying to run the "hello.js" from eclipse. code runs fine, I didn't get any error but I can't find the screenshot. Here is my java code which i used to execute "hello.js".

```
public class Image {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        System.out.println("inside main");

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\phantomjs\\bin\\phantomjs" + " hello.js");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
    bis.close();
    }
catch (Exception ex)
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's your working directory of the run configuration?

Comment: working directory D:\workspace

Comment: I take it you've looked into that directory and haven't seen the file?

Comment: No, can you give any idea. Cause I am not getting any error.

Comment: Add `var fs = require('fs'); console.log("DIR:" + fs.workingDirectory);` somewhere into your PhantomJS script.